# Iteration of a primeness-measuring function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question**

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\delta(n)$ denote the cardinality of the set $$\left\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \::\: 1 < a < n,\  1 < b < n,\  n|ab\!\: \right\}.$$ Let $D(n)$ denote the sequence obtained by iterating the map $x \mapsto \delta(x)$ on $n$, so that e.g. $D(6) = [6,4,1,0,0,0,\dots]$ and $D(12) = [12,17,0,0,0,\dots]$. The following questions concern the asymptotic behavior of the sequences $D(n)$.

> 1. What is the least $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} D(n)_k = +\infty$?
> 2. Can we find $n > 0$ such that $D(n)$ is periodic?

---

Notice that the density of pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but $n$ fails to divide $a$ and $b$ measures how far away $n$ is from being prime. This density is just $\frac{\delta(n)}{n^2}$. The sequence $\delta$ is [A268631](https://oeis.org/A268631).

**Observations**

The maps $(a,b) \mapsto (a,n-b)$ and $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ preserve membership in the set involved in the definition of $\delta(n)$, and fix only $(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2})$. Thus, the quantity $\delta(n)$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ precisely if $4$ divides $n$. Otherwise, $\delta(n)$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$. This provides a partial answer to Question 2: $D(n)$ cannot have odd period for $n > 0$, and in particular $n=0$ is the only solution to $\delta(n) = n$.

By writing the set $\left\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \::\: 1 < a < n,\  1 < b < n,\  n|ab \right\}$ as a union of periodic lattices corresponding to the divisors of $n$ (as in the figures below) I was able to determine, using elementary arguments, that $\delta(n) < n$ holds only in the following cases:

1. $n$ is prime and so $\delta(n) = 0 < n$;
2. $n=2p$ for some prime $p$, and then $\delta(2p) = 2(2-1)(p-1) = 2(p-1) < 2p$;
3. $n=p^2$ for some prime $p$, and then $\delta(p^2) = (p-1)^2 < p^2$;
4. $n=8$.

I feel that a negative answer to Question 2 should follow straightforwardly from here (but I'm not quite sure how to get it). It also suggests to me (perhaps naively) that $D(n)$ should diverge for many integers: since $2p$ is always congruent to $2$ modulo $4$, numbers of the form $2p$ cannot occur in any $D(n)$ with $n \neq 2p$, which leaves only the prime and prime square cases. But as the primes thin out, it seems likely that a sequence will never hit any of these. Does e.g. $D(45)$ grow without bound? It reaches 407425 in eight iterations.

---

[image: The set of delta(15) as a union of two lattices corresponding to the divisors 3 and 5. For distinct primes p,q, we have delta(pq) = 2(p-1)(q-1).]

[image: The set of delta(45) with the lattice corresponding to the divisor 15 highlighted in orange.]

---

Comment: Have you checked whether $\delta(n)$ is in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed I have, but unfortunately I did so at an earlier stage. In the original context from which I distilled this question, I worked with $n^2 - \delta(n)$. Since I could not find that in the OEIS, I assumed that $\delta(n)$ would not be there either. But now I see that $\delta(n)$ is OEIS A268631 (edit: added ref to question). Thanks!